# Link a Slack Channel button from Account doesn't display all existing Slack channels

Tags: slack, slack-salesforce-app

If you are using Sales Cloud for Slack integration, your Account (or Opportunity) object gets a new button called `Link a Sales Channel`

Clicking the button offers the option to create a new Slack channel or link to an existing one.

[image]

If you choose `An existing Slack channel`:

- You only see the oldest Slack channels in your Slack workspace. (In our case, *#dungeonsAndDragons, #starTrek, #coffee, #commuting* and their ilk)
- You don't see any new Slack channels, including public ones you created 5 minutes ago

How can you find from Salesforce the complete set of public Slack channels so you can create a link between your SFDC record and the Slack channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is (as of Spring 24), you can't -- but there is a workaround

There's a [Known Issue](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000xAOrwAAG/customer-cannot-see-list-of-all-slack-channel-in-link-a-sales-channel-salesforce-feature) that says:

> 'Link a sales channel' GA feature can only guarantee to list 200 slack channels for an
> existing workspace.
>
> The maximum allowed limit for the number of channels to be visible is 1000 channels.
>
> If there are archived channels within the first 1000 channels, it will only show the
> ones the user has created or the ones that are public.

In practice, since our Slack Workspace has been around for 8+ years, we have created and archived a lot of channels.  Hence, per the KI, we're only seeing the oldest non-archived public channels out of what I imagine are the oldest 1000 channels (speculation)

### Workaround

- Go to Slack, specifically the `Sales Cloud for Slack` app (labeled `Sales`)

[image]

- Select the app's Home page sub-tab and click `Create a Sales Channel`.
  [image]
- The dialog will allow you to choose any Slack channel (unless it has external members - not supported) and link to an Account or Opportunity

If this affects you, go to the KI and note that you report the same issue.